# error yarn package manager en debian 12

Tags: nodejs, yarn, laravel-10

tengo un proyecto en **Laravel 10 con Breeze** el cual he estado trabajándolo en una pc con windows y decidí hacer las actualizaciones del sistema según los nuevos requisitos en una pc con **Debian 12**. El problema viene cuando quiero ejecutar el servidor de **Node JS**, personalmente uso `yarn` como gestor de paquetes pero es que ni con `npm` me funciona, cuando ejecuto cualquier comando luego del nombre del gestor de paquetes me dice que no se reconocen esos comandos dentro del sistema, ya sea si uso `yarn dev` o `yarn vite` o si voy a instalar alguna dependencia. Probé crear un proyecto con `yarn` aparte y tampoco me deja, indagando en internet me decían que reinstalara las dependecias del backend con `composer` y que eliminara la carpeta `node_modules` y la volviera a crear con `yarn add` o `npm install` y me sigue dando el mismo error, no reconoce los comandos luego del nombre gestor de paquetes de **Node JS**

Este es el error que me muestra en la terminal cuando ejecuto `yarn dev`:

```
00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dev'
```

Cuando ejecuto `npm run dev` entonces me sale esto:

```
sh: 1: vite: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

ya que debian no tiene una version actualizada de nodejs, debes de instalarla con el script de [nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) con el comando, logueado como root

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash - &&\
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

para activar yarn debes ejecutar el siguiente comando como root

```bash
corepack enable
```

esto deberia solucionar tu problema

Comment: luego de ejecutar el primer comando que pones prosigo a importar yarn `curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/yarn-archive-keyring.gpg` y me sale este error `curl: (35) Recv failure: Conexión reinicializada por la máquina remota
gpg: no se han encontrados datos OpenPGP válidos`

Comment: @williamrb no debes ejecutar ningun comando extra.. porque haz colocado eso? yarn no se instala ya viene includo con nodejs solo hay que activar su modulo